# maven dependency for "org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift"

Tags: wso2, wso2-as

I am using "org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift-4.2.0" and ran into version conflictions regarding two dependents packages "xercesImpl-2.6.2" and "slf4j"

as a temporary solution I have to exclude the orignal version, (see below pom.xml)

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
 <!-- xercesImpl-2.6.2 had caused error with 
      com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver.createDocumentBuilderFactory()     

      <exclusions>      
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        </exclusion>        
      </exclusions>
-->      
    </dependency>


SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/wjz/.m2/repository/slf4j/wso2/slf4j/1.5.10.wso2v1/slf4j-1.5.10.wso2v1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/wjz/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.10 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]
```

I noticed that the WSO2 AS 5.3.0 has already using "org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift-4.4.7" in its releasing image.

I tried also to upgrade to 4.4.7 by change the version number to 4.4.7 in the pom.xml (see below)

```
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift</artifactId>
          <version>4.4.7</version>      
        </dependency>
```

and I got an error saying "Missing artifact org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift:jar:4.4.7"

I searched around the maven repo and wso2 nexus and found nothing.

so my question, where is the latest maven repo link by which I can fetch  new WSO2 packages

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group ids are different in 4.4.x jars. The one you are referring to should be changed like this.

```
<groupId>org.wso2.carbon.commons</groupId>
```